# Do I need to convert nil attributes to_s for views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails so please bear with me on this. I try to learn rails using the agile web-development book and of course had to try my own stuff and not follow the tutorial. Though I'm stuck at a strange behaviour when running rake test.

I get:

```
test_should_show_experiment(ExperimentsControllerTest):
ActionView::Template::Error: can't convert nil into String
```

and

```
test_should_get_index(ExperimentsControllerTest):
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

when running rake test.

In my views (index and show) I use

```
<%= image_tag experiment.image_url, :height => 32, :class => 'list_image' %>
```

when I change that into

```
<%= image_tag experiment.image_url.to_s, :height => 32, :class => 'list_image' %>
```

(adding .to_s to the image tag) all functional test are successful.

**Now to my question: Does rails require me to cast every possible nil value to a string in my case?**

Some information that might be useful to solve this question: 
My model looks like this:

```
class Experiment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :description, :image_url, :presence => true
  validates :name, :uniqueness => true
  validates :image_url, :format => {
    #:with => %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i,
    :with => /\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i,
    :message => 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
  }
end
```

I didn't touch the controller after the generate scaffold command.

```
class CreateExperiments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :experiments do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :experiments
  end
end

## another migration file because I wanted to add a column
class AddImageToExperiments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :experiments, :image_url, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :experiments, :image_url
  end
end
```

My test setup looks like this:

```
setup do
    @experiment = experiments(:one)
    @update = {
      :name => "JUST SOME UNIT TEST NAME", 
      :description => "JUST SOME UNIT TEST DESCRIPTION", 
      :image_url => "http://www.just-some-unit-test-url.example.com/image.jpg"
    }
end
```

I use @update in 'test "should create experiment" ... ' and 'test "should update experiment"' - this is where the errors are seeming to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error #1**

```
test_should_show_experiment(ExperimentsControllerTest):
ActionView::Template::Error: can't convert nil into String
```

You can't pass a **nil** value into an `image_tag` helper method.  If the image attribute is nil, you shouldn't be showing the image anyways.  Check it using `blank?` which checks for nil or empty attribute, and replace it with a default image of some kind.  I would not recommend using `nil.to_s` since it really buys you nothing.

```
<%= image_tag("#{experiment.image_url.blank? ? 'some_default_image.jpg' : experiment.image_url}", :height => 32, :class => 'list_image') %>
```

**Error #2**

```
test_should_get_index(ExperimentsControllerTest):
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

It's telling you that your `Experiment` object is **nil** and you're trying to get the `name` attribute of a nil object (which you can't do).  Make sure your experiments object is valid after you create it and that you're passing the instance variable (i.e. `@experiment`) into whatever view that you're calling `.name` on it

Answer (score 0):

```
test_should_get_index(ExperimentsControllerTest):
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

You should have information about where did error happen (maybe provide a view please).

Question: Does rails require me to cast every possible nil value to a string in my case?

You should care about exceptions. Possible way is:

```
<%= your_model.name rescue "- no name provided -" %>
```

Especially if you expect that name may be nil (I don't see validation for blank name in your model)